# Virtualising ubuntu-server on ubuntu using qemu

Tags: 13.10, qemu

I successfully created an qemu image containing ubuntu-server. I installed that image server instance using the "normal" option. When I boot up the image using

```
qemu  ubuntu-server-13.10.img -boot c -m 2000 -enable-kvm
```

first Grub appeares. If I choose "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and boot, the system dies at the stage "loading intial ramdisk"

Guest OS is Kubuntu 13.10 64bit, with latest updates, I created the image with qemu-system-x86_64.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for some reasons, the options found all over the internet to start the image like

```
qemu <imagefile> [-enable-kvm]
```

didn't work for me, however (strangely) the deprecated command

```
kvm <imagefile> did work.
```

So that's what I end up now and it works flawless:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -machine accel=kvm <imagefile>
```